# Example of a bounded set with measure zero, whose frontier has no measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am having a hard time trying to answer this question

*Give an example of a bounded set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ with zero measure such that $\partial X$ has no measure zero*

My attempt: Since $X$ has zero measure, then its interior is empty. So $\partial X$ is equal to the closure of $X$. Then I tried to manipulate Cantor set, since its frontier has no measure zero, but unsuccessfully.

I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the boundary of the set of all rational numbers?

Comment: Since its interior is empty, its closure and its frontier are the same. The closure of the rational numbers is the whole line.

Comment: So the rationals are an example in $\mathbb{R}^1$

Comment: you mean $X = [0 , 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ ? Since X is countable, it has measure zero. Clearly its interior is empty. And since its closure is equal to the interval [0, 1], then the measure of its closure is 1. I'm not sure about the last claim I made.

Comment: What you say is true, but you could also use $\mathbb{Q}$ as the example (in $\mathbb{R}^1$.)  $\mu(\mathbb{Q})=0,\ \mu(\mathbb{\partial{Q}})=\infty$

Comment: @saulspatz: The quesiton asked for a *bounded* set.

Comment: $([0,1]\cap \Bbb Q)^n$ is countable. And its boundary (frontier) is $[0,1]^n$  which has $n$-dimensional measure $1$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, I overlooked that; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comments, one example is $X = [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$, with $X \subset \mathbb{R}$. $X$ is bounded. $X$ has zero measure because $X$ is countable ($X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, which is countable). Finally, it's boundary $\partial X$ is $[0, 1]$, which does not have measure zero.